# Load section of html into div

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to load only a predetermined portion of an external html file into a div using jQuery?

If the external html is subdivided (like using `<div id="section1", "...2", "...3">` for instance) into separate sections, can jQuery fish out div id="section1" only and output that into destination div?

Can I tweak this code to accomplish that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url : "sourceFile.html",
        dataType : "html",
        success : function (data) {
            $("#targetDIV").html(data);
        },
        error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("doc did not load. Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("doc did not load. Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.load`

```
$("#targetDIV").load("sourceFile.html #section1");
```

Include a space after the file name with the specific content you wish to target from that file. API: http://api.jquery.com/load/